# NPE error when assigning variables (program does not crash, only debug shows NPE) - Android/Java

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, null

Im having an issue figuring out why some of my variables are not being set correctly. It seems that they only contain `null`. Below is the method that I am having the issue with. I should note that the program does not crash. I runs without issues (albeit not with expected behavior). Only when I use the built in debugger in Android Studio do I see that the values of `metadataInput`, `localOut`, `localZip` are null (actually, they point to a random address in memory, i.e. `com.android.File@251435672`).

If I set a `String` variable, called `S1` for example, equal to some string, and then set `metadataInput` equal to `S1`, 'metadataInput` is no longer pointing to a random memory address. Can anyone explain why it works one way but not the other?

Comment: Those variables are not `null`. What you are seeing is the default `toString()` representation of an object. I don't understand the last bit of your question. You can't set `metadataInput` equal to `S1` because `S1` is a `String` and `metadataInput` is a `FileOutputStream`. Are you actually getting a `NullPointerException` at all?

Comment: Apologies for the title. The NPE was displayed once when I was debugging the program. At the moment, I am getting the default `toString()` representation as you mentioned. `localZip' is the only one being shown as containing `null`. Is there a reason why the debugger would display the contents of `fileMetadata' as the actual string (e.x. "myFile.txt") and then display `metadataInput` as the `toString()` representation (e.x. com.android.File@251435672)?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a stacktrace if this is a NPE as you state. The reason for the program not crashing is you may be handling and "swallowing" your exceptions.

Consider removing catch blocks or re-throwing a RuntimeException wrapping the root cause to make you application crash - then address the cause of the crash!

Comment: Thats actually a good suggestion, I will give it a try and see exactly what happens. I have a feeling it will be a NPE though, since thats what the debugger listed at one point.